# Panda's dataframe split a column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe looks like as below:

```
date     |    location          | occurance <br>
------------------------------------------------------
somedate |united_kingdom_london | 5  
somedate |united_state_newyork  | 5
```

I want it to transform into

```
date     | country        | city    | occurance <br>
---------------------------------------------------
somedate | united kingdom | london  | 5  
---------------------------------------------------
somedate | united state   | newyork | 5
```

I am new to Python and after some research I have written following code, but seems to unable to extract country and city:

```
df.location= df.location.replace({'-': ' '}, regex=True)
df.location= df.location.replace({'_': ' '}, regex=True)

temp_location = df['location'].str.split(' ').tolist() 

location_data = pd.DataFrame(temp_location, columns=['country', 'city'])
```

I appreciate your response.

Comment: Thanks guys for your response. With given  context, all of your solutions works fine, but actual dataset I am working quite complicated. As a result, I was unable to work it out as yet. From above snippet of mine, after replacing '-', '_' I am doing    for item in temp:
    
    if str(item) == 'United':
        
        frames = [temp[0], temp[2].str.partition(" ", expand=True)]

        result = pd.concat(frames)
        print result //but this does not seems working

Answer (score 3):

Starting with this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['somedate', 'somedate'],
                   'location': ['united_kingdom_london', 'united_state_newyork'],
                   'occurence': [5, 5]})
```

Try this:

```
df['Country'] = df['location'].str.rpartition('_')[0].str.replace("_", " ")
df['City']    = df['location'].str.rpartition('_')[2]
df[['Date','Country', 'City', 'occurence']]

      Date        Country      City  occurence
0  somedate  united kingdom   london          5
1  somedate    united state  newyork          5
```

Borrowing idea from @MaxU

```
df[['Country'," " , 'City']] = (df.location.str.replace('_',' ').str.rpartition(' ', expand= True ))
df[['Date','Country', 'City','occurence' ]]

      Date        Country      City  occurence
0  somedate  united kingdom   london          5
1  somedate    united state  newyork          5
```

Comment: But you will have a empty column name in second method.

Comment: @shivsn, yes its not used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
temp_location = {}
splits = df['location'].str.split(' ')
temp_location['country'] = splits[0:-1].tolist() 
temp_location['city'] = splits[-1].tolist() 

location_data = pd.DataFrame(temp_location)
```

If you want it back in the original df:

```
df['country'] = splits[0:-1].tolist() 
df['city'] = splits[-1].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting the column's string value using [`rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['somedate', 'somedate'],
                   'location': ['united_kingdom_london', 'united_state_newyork'],
                   'occurence': [5, 5]})

df['country'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x[0:x.rfind('_')])
df['city'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x[x.rfind('_')+1:])

df = df[['Date', 'country', 'city', 'occurence']]
print(df)

#        Date         country     city  occurence
# 0  somedate  united_kingdom   london          5
# 1  somedate    united_state  newyork          5
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['somedate', 'somedate'],
                   'location': ['united_kingdom_london', 'united_state_newyork'],
                   'occurence': [5, 5]})

df.location = df.location.str[::-1].str.replace("_", " ", 1).str[::-1]
newcols = df.location.str.split(" ")
newcols = pd.DataFrame(df.location.str.split(" ").tolist(),
                         columns=["country", "city"])
newcols.country = newcols.country.str.replace("_", " ")
df = pd.concat([df, newcols], axis=1)
df.drop("location", axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)

         Date  occurence         country     city
  0  somedate          5  united kingdom   london
  1  somedate          5    united state  newyork
```

You could use regex in the replace for a more complicated pattern but if it's just the word after the last `_` I find it easier to just reverse the str twice as a hack rather than fiddling around with regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

I would use [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [107]: df
Out[107]:
       Date               location  occurence
0  somedate  united_kingdom_london          5
1  somedate   united_state_newyork          5
2  somedate         germany_munich          5

In [108]: df[['country','city']] = (df.location.str.replace('_',' ')
   .....:                             .str.extract(r'(.*)\s+([^\s]*)', expand=True))

In [109]: df
Out[109]:
       Date               location  occurence         country     city
0  somedate  united_kingdom_london          5  united kingdom   london
1  somedate   united_state_newyork          5    united state  newyork
2  somedate         germany_munich          5         germany   munich

In [110]: df = df.drop('location', 1)

In [111]: df
Out[111]:
       Date  occurence         country     city
0  somedate          5  united kingdom   london
1  somedate          5    united state  newyork
2  somedate          5         germany   munich
```

PS please be aware that it's not possible to parse properly (to distinguish) between rows containing two-words country + one-word city and rows containing one-word country + two-words city (unless you have a full list of countries so you check it against this list)...